# how to org-toggle-todo-heading?

Tags: org-mode, todo

The function `org-toggle-heading` is quite handy to convert existing text into an org heading.

Input:

```
pay rent
```

Output:

```
* pay rent
```

The function `org-insert-heading` has an analogous `org-insert-todo-heading`, but I don't see the function `org-toggle-todo-heading` as a counterpart to `org-toggle-heading`.

Desired output:

```
* TODO pay rent
```

Is there a function to convert existing text into org todo heading?

Comment: On a side note, you can easily convert `abc` or a list element `- abc` to `* abc` using the default binding `C-c *`. `C-c -` will convert to a list element instead of heading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## My preferred implementation

This alternative solution will *not* act as a toggle, but it will directly convert `Heading` to `* TODO Heading` on hitting `C-c C-t` (The Shift bindings will not work here).

The advantage of this approach is that you do not need to remember a new function or binding just for this special plain text to TODO conversion; the `C-c C-t` default binding for `org-todo` will work in DWIM fashion.

For instance, both of the below conversions happen when using the same `C-c C-t` binding:

```
Heading▮   -- (C-c C-t)--> * TODO Heading▮
* Heading▮ -- (C-c C-t)--> * TODO Heading▮
```

**Implementation**

```el
(defun modi/org-first-convert-to-heading (orig-fun &rest args)
  (let ((is-heading))
    (save-excursion
      (forward-line 0)
      (when (looking-at "^\\*")
        (setq is-heading t)))
    (unless is-heading
      (org-toggle-heading))
    (apply orig-fun args)))
(advice-add 'org-todo :around #'modi/org-first-convert-to-heading)
```

*You need to be using emacs 24.4+ for the above advice system to work.*

---

### Toggle current line between a non-heading and `TODO` heading

Below function will work on a non-empty line as follows:

If the line contains

```
Heading▮
```

`M-x my/org-toggle-heading-and-todo` will convert that to,

```
* TODO Heading▮
```

Calling that function again will convert it back to,

```
Heading▮
```

#### Defining `my/org-toggle-heading-and-todo`

```el
(defun my/org-toggle-heading-and-todo ()
  "Toggles the current line between a non-heading and TODO heading."
  (interactive)
  (let ((is-heading))
    (save-excursion
      (forward-line 0)
      (when (looking-at "^\\*") 
        (setq is-heading t)))
    (if is-heading 
        (progn
          (org-todo 'none) ; remove TODO
          (org-toggle-heading)) ; remove heading
      (progn
        (org-toggle-heading) ; convert to heading
        (org-todo 'nextset))))) ; add TODO
```

---

### Cycle only the `TODO` states

**While the point is anywhere on the heading**, `S-right`/`S-left` will cycle through all the `TODO` states. *This works even if `shift-select-mode` is `t`. The key is to have the point/cursor on the heading.* I also noticed that the `org-treat-S-cursor-todo-selection-as-state-change` is `t` by default (and that's why the shift bindings for changing `TODO` states work).

Example:

Below, the point is on the heading

```
* Heading▮
```

After pressing `S-right`, I get,

```
* TODO Heading▮
```

After pressing `S-left`, I once again get,

```
* Heading▮
```

[**Reference**](http://orgmode.org/manual/TODO-basics.html)

*My org version as of writing this is 8.2.10.*

Comment: Well of course. Or you can just type in `* TODO` manually. I'm asking for a function that will do it for me automatically, since I do it many times a day.

Comment: Maybe the answer could be expanded to include an example of how to use `(org-todo "TODO")` following the function that the original poster is calling to insert the asterisk?  See the doc-string of `org-todo` for all the available options . . .

Comment: @incandescentman To allow me to help better, can you please answer the following? (1) Are you looking for an interactive solution or elisp solution? I am wondering because you are referring to function names rather than the more convenient bindings. (2) How is navigating and then typing/deleting `TODO` better than a quick `S-right` or `S-left`? (3) How many todo states do you plan to use? By default, you need to cycle, not toggle the todo states: *nothing* -> `TODO` -> `DONE` -> *nothing*.

Comment: S-right and S-left require org-support-shift-select to be turned off. Surely there's a universal solution that doesn't require me to turn that setting off and on. And org-todo cycling only works on headings, not plain text.

Comment: @incandescentman Instead of the Shift bindings, you can also use `C-c C-t` to do the same state cycling, which is bound to `org-todo` function. You can customize the todo states by customizing `org-todo-keywords`. Or do quickly want to go from `Heading` to `* TODO Heading`? There is no function like that but one can be easily made that does the job of `C-c * S-right`.

Comment: Incorrect. `C-c C-t` only works on headings, not on plain text.

Comment: Only headings can have TODO states. I'll shortly update the answer with a wrapper function that does the job of `C-c * S-right`. Do you have CUA mode enabled? I don't use shift select. That's a separate discussion, but shift select is less efficient than `set-mark-command` (`C-space`) approach of selection.

Comment: @incandescentman Correct, only headings can have todo states (org rules). As I mentioned above, you'll need a wrapper function to do two steps: 1. Convert to heading `C-c *`.     2. Convert to TODO `S-right` or `C-c C-t`.

Comment: @incandescentman Improved the solution even more; try using the solution with advice and the use of `C-c C-t` bindings.

Comment: What does `S-` stand for alt key?

Comment: @alper Shift key. Alt or Meta would be `M-` and Ctrl is `C-`.